# How to set 3 axis in google chart (V-Axis Left as Qty, V-Axis Right as Series Column and H-Axis as TimeOrder)?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization, chart.js

Hi there all I have a Query How I can set up three Axis in Google Chart, I'm using these code down below and it's working fine with 2 Axis But I need to add Date on Right-Axis and Qty on Left-Axis and order-time on Bottom-Axis. I put the demo data in chart basically I get data from database using PHP fetch and show in the chart.

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Ordertime', 'Qty'],
  ['0', 24],
  ['1', 15],
  ['2', 10],
  ['3', 34],
  ['4', 65],
  ['5', 72],
  ['6', 18],
  ['7', 73],
  ['8', 80],
  ['9', 50],
  ['10', 40],
  ['11', 49],
  ['12', 70],
]);

var options = {
  title:'Sales by Category (Arabi) Branch (Madinah) Date (2018-03-15)',
  hAxis: {title: 'Sales By Time',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
  vAxis: {minValue: 0},
  series: {
            0: { color: '#885426' },
            1: { color: '#008000' },
          },
  areaOpacity: 0.1,
  pointSize: 5,
        
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
  <!-- Chart js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <!-- JQuery JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML Tag -->
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

What I need I show you example picture which I get from phpmyadmin  Display-Chart, Picture down below ....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeVP0.png)

Using this PHP code to Get data from the database

```
<?php
$sql="  SELECT hoursales.opendate,location.locname,category.catname,category.catid,hoursales.ordertime, 
  SUM(hoursales.qty) as Qty, 
  SUM(hoursales.amount) as Amount
  FROM hoursales,product,prodho,category,location
  where hoursales.prodn=prodho.prodnum
  and category.catid=prodho.catidho
  and hoursales.locid=location.locid
  and prodho.locid=location.locid
  and product.catidho=category.catid
  and hoursales.prodn=prodho.prodnum
  and product.prodnumho=prodho.prodnumho
  and (hoursales.opendate='$_POST[fst_date]' or hoursales.opendate='$_POST[snd_date]')
  and location.locid='$_POST[branch]'
  and category.catid='$_POST[category]'
  and hoursales.ordertime BETWEEN '0' and '23'
  GROUP BY hoursales.opendate, category.catname,hoursales.ordertime";
  $search_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))  {
   $ordertime = $row['ordertime'];
   $opendate = $row['opendate'];
   $qty = $row['Qty'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to produce the desired chart,
the data would need to be structured as follows,
with a column of values for each date...

```
['Ordertime', '2018-02-15', '2018-02-22'],
['0', 24, 26],
['1', 15, 13],
['2', 10, 15],
['3', 34, 30],
['4', 65, 67],
['5', 72, 70],
['6', 18, 20],
['7', 73, 70],
['8', 80, 85],
['9', 50, 55],
['10', 40, 43],
['11', 49, 48],
['12', 70, 70]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Ordertime', '2018-02-15', '2018-02-22'],
    ['0', 24, 26],
    ['1', 15, 13],
    ['2', 10, 15],
    ['3', 34, 30],
    ['4', 65, 67],
    ['5', 72, 70],
    ['6', 18, 20],
    ['7', 73, 70],
    ['8', 80, 85],
    ['9', 50, 55],
    ['10', 40, 43],
    ['11', 49, 48],
    ['12', 70, 70]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 60,
      left: 60,
      right: 160,
      bottom: 60
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    title: 'Sales by Category (Arabi) Branch (Madinah) Date (2018-03-15)',
    hAxis: {title: 'Sales By Time',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    series: {
      0: { color: '#885426' },
      1: { color: '#008000' },
    },
    areaOpacity: 0.1,
    pointSize: 5,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```